# Can't rollback with --step a single column

Tags: laravel

So I just added a colum via `php artisan migrate` to an `orders` table.

This colum was added via `php artisan make:migration add_balance_to_orders_table --table=orders` command.

If I `php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1` I get this:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::dropColum does not exist.

> Bad Method Call: Did you mean Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::dropColumn() ?

when `dropColum` is present.

This is how it looks:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddBalanceToOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->float('balance');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColum('balance');
        });
    }
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: check-in the database and see if it is existed or not

Comment: You have the typo there, fix it with `dropColumn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like it says in the error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::dropColum does not exist.

> Bad Method Call: Did you mean
> Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::dropColumn() ?

you gave the `dropColum` change it to `dropColumn` like below

```
public function down()
        {
            Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropColumn('balance');
            });
        }
```

and then run the

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1
```

Hope it works for you